# Issue in the proof showing that the splitting fields are normal.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, normal-extension

I am using the following definition of a normal extension: $K \subset L$ is normal if for all $\Omega$ with $K \subset \Omega$, for all $K$ embeddings $x_1:L\rightarrow \Omega, x_2:L\rightarrow \Omega$, we have that $x_1(L) \subset x_2(L)$.

I was given a proof that splitting fields are normal which goes as follows:
$K \subset L$ a splitting field for some $f(x) \in K[X]$.
Then, it is immediately assumed that $L \subset \Omega$, $x:L \rightarrow \Omega$ is a $K$-embedding, and then shown that $x(L)=L$. This concludes the proof (I didn't add much detail to this hoping it's not necessary for my question). I understand most of what is going on in the proof, the only issue is this assumption that we can take $L \subset \Omega$. The definition states that the property must hold for all $\Omega$ such that $K \subset \Omega$, however we show it for all $\Omega$ such that $L \subset \Omega$. How is it possible to make such a reduction?

Comment: You may assume $L\subset\Omega$ by identifying it with its image under the embedding $x_1$. You have rewrite it to use an arbitrary embedding $x_1$. In other words, replace $L$ with $x_1(L)$, which is “essentially the same” as $L$.

Comment: Something along the lines of taking an arbitrary $K$-embedding $y:L \rightarrow \Omega$ and then writing another $K$-embedding $x: L \rightarrow \Omega$ as $x \circ y^{-1} : y(L) \rightarrow \Omega$?

Comment: Pretty much, but without the cumbersome extra embedding being lugged around.

Comment: Ok, I think i got it, thanks a bunch!